# using UIBezierPath for setting radius to some corners and adding shadow to Custom UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have a custom UIButton.
I want to add radius to some corners (not to all of them)
I'm using UIBezierPath for setting that.
But because i'm masking the layer i cant add a shadow.

For all corners it works:

```
func setupView() {
    layer.cornerRadius = 10
    addShadow(UIColor.blackColor(), opacity: 0.8, radius: 5, offset: CGSizeMake(1, 1))
}

func addShadow(color: UIColor, opacity: Float, radius: CGFloat, offset: CGSize){
    layer.shadowColor = color.CGColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    layer.shadowRadius = radius
    layer.shadowOffset = offset
}
```

For some corners using UIBezierPath i get only the rounded corners but no shadow

```
func setupView() {
    addCornerRadiusToCurners(false, leftTop: true, rightBottom: false, leftBottom: false, radius: 10)
    addShadow(UIColor.blackColor(), opacity: 0.8, radius: 5, offset: CGSizeMake(1, 1))
}


func addCornerRadiusToCurners(rightTop: Bool = true, leftTop: Bool = true, rightBottom: Bool = true, leftBottom: Bool = true, radius: CGFloat) {

    var corners: UIRectCorner = []

    if rightTop {  corners.insert(.TopRight)  }
    if leftTop { corners.insert(.TopLeft) }
    if rightBottom {  corners.insert(.BottomRight) }
    if leftBottom { corners.insert(.BottomLeft) }

    let cornerPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(radius, radius))
    let cornerMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    cornerMaskLayer.path = cornerPath.CGPath
    layer.mask = cornerMaskLayer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this updated CustomButton class:

class CustomButton: UIButton {

```
var cornerMaskLayer : CAShapeLayer!
var corners: UIRectCorner = []
var cornerRadius : CGFloat = 0

override func awakeFromNib() {
    addCornerRadiusToCurners(radius: 10)
    addShadow(UIColor.blackColor(), opacity: 0.5, radius: 2.0, offset: CGSizeMake(2, 5))
}

func addShadow(color: UIColor, opacity: Float, radius: CGFloat, offset: CGSize){
    layer.shadowColor = color.CGColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    layer.shadowRadius = radius
    layer.shadowOffset = offset
}

func setupView() {
    addCornerRadiusToCurners(false, leftTop: true, rightBottom: false, leftBottom: false, radius: 10)
    addShadow(UIColor.blackColor(), opacity: 0.8, radius: 5, offset: CGSizeMake(1, 1))
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let cornerPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(cornerRadius, cornerRadius))

    cornerMaskLayer.path = cornerPath.CGPath

}


func addCornerRadiusToCurners(rightTop: Bool = true, leftTop: Bool = true, rightBottom: Bool = true, leftBottom: Bool = true, radius: CGFloat) {

    if rightTop {  corners.insert(.TopRight)  }
    if leftTop { corners.insert(.TopLeft) }
    if rightBottom {  corners.insert(.BottomRight) }
    if leftBottom { corners.insert(.BottomLeft) }

    cornerRadius = radius

    let cornerPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(radius, radius))
    cornerMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    cornerMaskLayer.path = cornerPath.CGPath
    cornerMaskLayer.fillColor = self.backgroundColor?.CGColor
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    layer.addSublayer(cornerMaskLayer);
}
```

}

Result is [image: Output]

Comment: This isn't working for me. it makes the full screen as the color of the button

Comment: This is because of button size varied for different devices, Updated code.

Comment: Please share your sample app